# TryStrToFloat converts incorrect string

Tags: string, delphi, type-conversion

I'm using `TryStrToFloat` to convert string to Double variables. Everything works fine until string doesn't looks like '21e'. I get result of conversion 21.

It seems to me that compiler treats '21e' like number 21e0. String 21e1 gives result 210.
When I use Val function conversion works better. String '21e' gives error, but now '21e1' gives 210, '21e-1' gives number 2,1 etc.

How to make correct working of conversion. Should I detect letter 'e' in text, or is any simply way to convert ?

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) says:

> Use TryStrToFloat to convert a string, S, to a floating-point value. S must consist of an optional sign (+ or -), a string of digits with an optional decimal point, and an optional mantissa. The mantissa consists of 'E' or 'e' followed by an optional sign (+ or -) and a whole number. Leading and trailing blanks are ignored.

Your input does not satisfy the conditions and so should be treated as an error.

You did not say so explicitly, but I presume that you claim that:

```
TryStrToFloat('21e', val)
```

returns `True`. If so, this is a bug and should be reported to Embarcadero. If you need to work around this then I suggest you code your own function that detects this case and handles it correctly.

On the other hand, if that function call returns `False` the function is behaving as designed and your mistake is to read the value in `val`.

**Update**

I can confirm that `TryStrToFloat('21e', val)` returns `True`. I tested on XE7 update 1. I submitted the following bug report to Embarcadero: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9814

Comment: Indeed. `TextToFloat` (called by `TryStrToFloat`) returns `TRUE` for `21e`. Tested with XE, that's the most current I have on that machine here.

Comment: Thank you @JensG, as I guess you could tell I had not been able to verify this problem.